How to Bound TypeVar Correctly to Protocol?
I want to type annotate a simple sorting function that receives a list of any values that have either __lt__, __gt__, or both, but not mixed methods (i.e., all values should have the same comparison method) and returns a list containing the same elements it received in sorted order.
What I've done so far:
from typing import Any, Protocol

class SupportsLT(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, other: Any, /) -> bool: ...

class SupportsGT(Protocol):
    def __gt__(self, other: Any, /) -> bool: ...

def quick_sort[T: SupportsLT | SupportsGT](seq: list[T]) -> list[T]:
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        return list(seq)
    pivot = seq[0]
    smaller: list[T] = []
    larger_or_equal: list[T] = []
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        item = seq[i]
        if item < pivot:
            smaller.append(item)
        else:
            larger_or_equal.append(item)
    return [*quick_sort(smaller), pivot, *quick_sort(larger_or_equal)]

Running mypy --strict gives the error: error: Unsupported left operand type for < (some union)  [operator]. I think this is because there is no guarantee that the values do not have mixed protocols.
Another attempt is using constraints instead of bound:
def quick_sort[T: (SupportsLT, SupportsGT)](seq: list[T]) -> list[T]:
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        return list(seq)
    pivot = seq[0]
    smaller: list[T] = []
    larger_or_equal: list[T] = []
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        item = seq[i]
        if item < pivot:
            smaller.append(item)
        else:
            larger_or_equal.append(item)
    return [*quick_sort(smaller), pivot, *quick_sort(larger_or_equal)]

When I run mypy --strict, I get complaints about the type of the list returned by the return statement:
error: List item 0 has incompatible type "list[T]"; expected "SupportsLT"  [list-item]
error: List item 0 has incompatible type "list[T]"; expected "SupportsGT"  [list-item]
error: List item 2 has incompatible type "list[T]"; expected "SupportsLT"  [list-item]
error: List item 2 has incompatible type "list[T]"; expected "SupportsGT"  [list-item]

However, the second attempt has a significant issue. Running the following gives Revealed type is "builtins.list[SupportsLT]", which should be "builtins.list[builtins.int]" instead:
from typing import reveal_type

x = quick_sort([12, 3])
reveal_type(x)

python version: 3.13.0, mypy version: 1.13.0
UPDATE:
The reason I'm using both SupportsLT and SupportsGT as bound while my function only utilizes the less-than operator (i.e., <) is that when the left-hand operand lacks the __lt__ method, Python calls the __gt__ method of the right-hand operand and passes the left operand as an argument. Thus, values with only __gt__ should be considered valid as input to my function. Consider the following simple example:
from typing import Self

class HasGT:
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __gt__(self, other: Self) -> bool:
        return self.value > other.value

print(HasGT(5) < HasGT(6))  # Prints True


As mentioned in the answer, your code only ever uses < so it is not clear why you want to allow SupportsGT?

Oh, this is painful. You can't use a typevar bound to union of the protocols, mypy is correct. If the input contains a mix of HasGT and HasLT types, which is allowed by such union, your function will eventually try to compare HasGT() < HasLT() and die. Restricting to "either all have gt or all have lt" is one of your options, you can do that using two overloads (then annotating impl with Any or adding a few ignore comments, I believe).

(a simple failing input should be quick_sort([HasLT(2), HasGT(3)]) where HasLT is the same as your HasGT in the last snippet with s/__gt__/__lt__)

@STerliakov With the original implementation (i.e., first code snippet), mypy correctly complains about the heterogeneous types in your example (error: Value of type variable "T" of "quick_sort" cannot be "object"  [type-var]).

Sorry, I forgot we still have to convince mypy to use union instead of meet, try foo: list[HasLT | HasGT] = [HasLT(2), HasGT(3)]; quick_sort(foo) - mypy should accept that. It's not a bug, this behavior is correct: a union is assignable to a union

Union bound
Your first attempt is indeed unsafe. Let's see that:
class HasGT:
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __gt__(self, other: Self) -> bool:
        return self.value > other.value


class HasLT:
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other: Self) -> bool:
        return self.value < other.value


foo: list[HasLT | HasGT] = [HasLT(2), HasGT(3)]
sorted_foo = quick_sort(foo)

mypy accepts this part (the error points at your definition), but it fails at runtime:
$ mypy s.py --strict
s.py:17: error: Unsupported left operand type for < (some union)  [operator]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

$ python s.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/temp/s.py", line 56, in <module>
    sorted_foo = quick_sort(foo)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/temp/s.py", line 17, in quick_sort
    if item < pivot:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'HasGT' and 'HasLT'

TypeVar bound to some type T can be substituted with any T1 <= T. Where T is a union type, there's nothing wrong with T1 being the same union type, that's explicitly allowed. So such implementation is unsafe.
Constrained typevar
Your second snippet is actually safe. There's a mypy bug making it reject your function as-is (something shady happens during unpacking, I'll have a look later), but replacing the last line with
return quick_sort(smaller) + [pivot] + quick_sort(larger_or_equal)

fixes things. Such implementation passes mypy --strict, but is barely useful as you noticed: it's return type will be just that, a protocol with a single comparison method.
Reasonable compromise
I think that it's reasonable to say "my implementation is fine" and provide the best possible signature for callers. It's reasonable to assume that the input collection is homogeneous, so let's just make two overloads (and also avoid restricting the input to lists: it works for any sequence):
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Any, Protocol, Self, overload

# [snip] Supports{L,G}T and Has{L,G}T definitions here

@overload
def quick_sort_overloaded[T: SupportsLT](seq: Sequence[T]) -> list[T]: ...
@overload
def quick_sort_overloaded[T: SupportsGT](seq: Sequence[T]) -> list[T]: ...
def quick_sort_overloaded[T: SupportsLT | SupportsGT](seq: Sequence[T]) -> list[T]:
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        return list(seq)
    pivot = seq[0]
    smaller: list[T] = []
    larger_or_equal: list[T] = []
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        item = seq[i]
        if item < pivot:  # type: ignore[operator]
            smaller.append(item)
        else:
            larger_or_equal.append(item)
    return [
        *quick_sort_overloaded(smaller),  # type: ignore[type-var]
        pivot, 
        *quick_sort_overloaded(larger_or_equal)  # type: ignore[type-var]
    ]

And now
reveal_type(quick_sort_overloaded([HasLT(2), HasLT(3)])) # N: Revealed type is "builtins.list[__main__.HasLT]"
reveal_type(quick_sort_overloaded([HasGT(2), HasGT(3)]))  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.list[__main__.HasGT]"

foo: list[HasLT | HasGT] = [HasLT(2), HasGT(3)]
try:
    quick_sort_overloaded(foo)  # E: Value of type variable "T" of "quick_sort_overloaded" cannot be "HasLT | HasGT"  [type-var]
except TypeError:
    print("`quick_sort_overloaded` failed as warned")

Here's a playground to compare all those solutions.

Many thanks. Why does using constraints make mypy or any other type checker think the return type is a simple protocol?

@CleverBoy Because that's how they work: constrained typevars can only be substituted with their exact constraints. It's occasionally useful, but I have encountered only few such cases. https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar

Given that your Quicksort function only ever performs comparisons on the line if item < pivot:, the requirement here should be that the elements of the list support <, i.e., you need elements that follow the SupportsLT protocol. The following code type checks with strict mypy (using Python 3.10, hence the use of TypeVar, though this should hold for later versions too):
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar


class SupportsLT(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, other: Any, /) -> bool: ...


T = TypeVar("T", bound=SupportsLT)


def quick_sort(seq: list[T]) -> list[T]:
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        return list(seq)
    pivot = seq[0]
    smaller: list[T] = []
    larger_or_equal: list[T] = []
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        item = seq[i]
        if item < pivot:
            smaller.append(item)
        else:
            larger_or_equal.append(item)
    return [*quick_sort(smaller), pivot, *quick_sort(larger_or_equal)]


print(quick_sort([3, 4, 1, 77, 2, 19, 24, -8, 0]))
# [-8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 19, 24, 77]
print(quick_sort(["hello", "world", "python", "is", "awesome"]))
# ['awesome', 'hello', 'is', 'python', 'world']
print(quick_sort([3, 4, 1, 77, "hello", "world"]))  # mypy flags this
# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
print(quick_sort([{1: 2}, {3: 4}]))  # mypy flags this
# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict

If you mean to have a mix of types (like in the third example from the code above), then you'll run into TypeErrors when elements only support comparison with certain other objects, but as the example shows, mypy will catch these, at least for builtins.

If a type only implements the __gt__ method, it can still be used with the less-than operator (i.e., <). When the left-hand operand lacks the __lt__ method, Python will simply call the __gt__ method of the right-hand operand and pass the left operand as other (e.g., x < y is the same as y > x). Thus, values with only __gt__ should be considered valid as input. I'm trying to be as generic as possible with the accepted input types.

@CleverBoy I see. I didn't know that Python would use that sort of trick for comparison when it's undefined the usual way. Your first attempt then looks like the right way to go about it, but mypy simply guards against < comparison for union types, so I'm not sure how you could get it to be happy (without simply adding # type: ignore to the one line that performs a comparison).

You may simply want to follow this answer and catch/raise errors when the comparison fails instead of controlling the input type, though this is of course not an answer to your original question.
